# Any recommended de-noise algorithm?

Tags: image-processing, noise-reduction

I'm trying to get rid of noise in the grayscale image. I tried the non-local-mean and Gaussian filter, but none of them give me good results. Is there any recommended algorithm I can use?

[image]

Comment: “I tried...” Please *show* what you did, don’t *tell* what you did. In particular, filtering requires a lot of parameter tuning to adjust it to the problem. The parameters you picked were likely inadequate for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are hoping for, but here each pixel is replaced by the mean of the surrounding 49x49 pixels just using **ImageMagick** in the Terminal:

```
convert noise.png -statistic mean 49x49 result.png
```

[image]

Here's the median of the surrounding 25x25 pixels:

```
convert noise.png -statistic median 25x25 result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Imagemagick, you can use the kuwahara non-linear edge preserving filter with different values (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuwahara_filter). Choose whichever looks best to you.

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.png -kuwahara 5 k5.png
```

[image]

```
convert img.png -kuwahara 9 k9.png
```

[image]

```
convert img.png -kuwahara 15 k15.png
```

[image]

```
convert img.png -kuwahara 25 k25.png
```

[image]